# Nexus card interview questions, not living in Canada yet?

Tags: nexus, canadian-residents

I got my Canadian PR 6 months ago but haven't moved there yet. I am living in US since last 8 years and this makes me eligible for Nexus card. I will be giving my interview this week. I would like to know people's experiences with these interviews and the kind of questions they ask. My main objective in getting the Nexus card is the possibility of using fast lanes during land/air travel. I am already conditionally approved but worried about CBSA asking residency questions (I still have 2.5 years technically to live outside Canada and still satisfy RO).

Answer (score 2):

Are you a permanent resident of the US?  If so, you also qualify for NEXUS, and should have no problem:  https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/nexus-eligibility ... just be sure to notify the NEXUS enrolment office of your change of circumstances once you relocate to Canada.

It sounds to me like you qualify now, and you will qualify once you move, so enrol now based on your current qualifications.  Answer any questions they ask honestly.  Your eligibility will, for now, be determined outside of your intent to immigrate to Canada.

Comment: No, I am in the US on a visa that expires next year so I will be moving to Canada latest by next year (so I will be satisfying my RO anyway, I just hope the CBSA officer doesn't reject my NEXUS application or says "oh you should've moved there already". To be fair there's no law that states when I should move, as long as I satisfy the RO).

Comment: @CJH the worst case scenario is that your Canadian permanent resident status will expire and you'd have to reapply.  That wouldn't invalidate your eligibility for NEXUS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will be making sure it doesn't expire :). I will be moving there next year at the latest and I still have 2.5 years to go (out of the 5 years) and still satisfy RO.

Comment: how did your interview go ? I am in a similar situation and have an interview tomorrow .